# example projects with hibernate and JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, persistence

Does anyone know a good open-source project where I could have a look on the persistence layer (for good programming practices and transaction management) where Hibernate 3 and JPA 1 is used?

Comment: With the information provided, this is a bit broad.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't tell you of any open source projects you can check out, but if you want to learn hibernate I can recommend a great book from Apress. It is called Hibernate Recipes and it pretty much explains everything.

**PS: no kind of advertising intended, just trying to help OP.**

Answer (score 0):

Try to search Bitbucket or GitHub repositories for "Hibernate", you will find a lot of sample projects you can learn best practices from.

Comment: that is what I am doing right now ;)